# How can I access nested arrays in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, request

I'm using jquery nested form repeater. When I submit form I get these values.

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#51 ▼
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#52 ▼
    #parameters: array:22 [▼
      "_token" => "brgVhd3F1K0wWqxsjDn6Vf9gBdKLX8CO8XbpkBJJ"
      "options" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:4 [▼
          "name" => "Color"
          "type" => "dropdown"
          "is_required" => array:1 [▶]
          "values" => array:1 [▼
            0 => array:3 [▼
              "label" => "Red"
              "price" => "100"
              "price_type" => "fixed"
            ]
          ]
        ]
        1 => array:3 [▼
          "name" => "Size"
          "type" => "dropdown"
          "values" => array:1 [▼
            0 => array:3 [▼
              "label" => "s"
              "price" => "100"
              "price_type" => "percent"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried using this. But it's give me Trying to get property 'name' of non-object;

```
foreach ($request->input('options') as $option) {

    Option::create([

        'name' => $option->name,

        'type' => $option->type,

         'is_required' => (boolean) $option->is_required
    ]);


     $option->values()->createMany($request->input('options.*.values'));

}
```

How can I access values?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I am using this $request->input('options.*.values');

Comment: Wait Please.. I am updating my question form more spacefic.

Comment: Please ca you show the output of `dd($request->all());`.

Comment: My form is too long so show my some part using dd

Comment: What is the problem And where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yeah. I got Trying to get property 'name' of non-object.

Comment: I think your logic is wrong. why you loop options, and use each option createMany all option's values?

Comment: If you're ever getting an error it's always a good idea to add that sort of information to your question.

Comment: It's give me same error.

Comment: Yes. But  I didn't put because I was confused. I'm doning right or wrong.

Comment: If I use each How i could access $request variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is because `$request->input()` will return an array not objects so for the most part you were just trying to access the property in the wrong way i.e. `$options->name` should have been `$options['name']`.

Secondly, `$option->values()->createMany($request->input('options.*.values'));` wouldn't have worked either as it would have returned a nested array of all the values and not just the ones for that option.

The following should get you what you're after:

```
foreach ($request->input('options') as $option) {

    $option = Option::create([
        'name'        => $option['name'],
        'type'        => $option['type'],
        'is_required' => (boolean)$option['is_required'],
    ]);

    $option->values()->createMany($option['values']);
}
```

---

This is just an FYI.

I would recommend using the [$casts](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) property inside your Eloquent model if you're not already:

```
protected $casts = [
    'is_required' => 'boolean',
];
```

This way you can tell Eloquent that `is_required` is meant to be a boolean and you then won't have to cast it yourself so in your foreach loop

```
'is_required' => (boolean)$option['is_required'],
```

would just be

```
'is_required' => $option['is_required'],
```

Comment: Thanks. It's Working. But What if I want to get direct from request without input?

Comment: @ShahadatHossain  I'm not sure what you mean since  `input` is from the request. Please may you explain in more detail.

Comment: I mean there have any other way without this $request->input('options'). Like $request->something

Comment: @ShahadatHossain You could use `$request->options`.

Comment: I have another thing to know... without loop through have any other way to insert to my Option model?

Comment: My last question is if I add is_required to my cast array its give me error is_required  can not be null. why?

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable time. I don't know you. but I think your are great.

Comment: Are you there? I have another problem.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain What is the problem?

Comment: "attributes" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          "attribute_id" => "5"
          "attribute_value_id" => array:3 [▶]
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
          "attribute_id" => "7"
          "attribute_value_id" => array:1 [▶]
        ]
      ]

Comment: when I use dd($request->input('attributes'))  I got array. Bu this  dd($request->attributes); dont return anything.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain  This is because `attributes` is actually a property on the `Request` object. Laravel allows you to access input values in the request as properties by using the magic method `__get()` which will only work if the value you're trying to access doesn't exist as a property on the class. This is why it's more beneficial to use the `input()` method.

Comment: I understand but why works for option not for attributes? I this is same thinf option and attribute. If you look option and attribute. There have built in property so that?

Comment: @ShahadatHossain There isn't an `options` property on the `Request` class but there is an `attributes` which is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following method

```
foreach ($request['options'] as $option) {
    Option::create([
        'name' => $option->name,
        'type' => $option->type,
         'is_required' => (boolean) $option->is_required
    ]);
    $option->values()->createMany($request->input('options.*.values'));
}
```